# Downloading webpages using sessions/cookies with TDownloadUrl (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, html, session-cookies, delphi-xe2

I've been testing some samples to save webpages using TDownloadUrl, and it was really amazing, but I found some problems certain webpages, those pages cannot let to access to real content because they need to start a session o set a cookie before, so I get two situations, **TDownloadUrl does**...

1. not create/save a file with content from webpage supposedly downloaded (STATUS CODE : 5 --> dsEndDownloadData), this is because there is no cookie (STATUS CODE : 41 --> dsCookieStateDowngrade)
2. not save the content right instead of it saves a webpage requesting to press a link to access to content wished

Is there any way to bypass these problems using Delphi's native components, that is, no third-party components (like TEmbeddedWB)?

Thanks in advance.

Note: I'm using Delphi XE2 under WinXP with Firefox 6.0 and IE 9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XE2 ships with Indy 10 (which is a third-party component, but at least it is a bundled one).  You can use its `TIdHTTP` component instead of `TDownloadURL`.  `TIdHTTP` supports cookies.